# What is "territorial state" in this context?

Tags: word-meaning

> The 26 cantons, with their different traditions, histories,
> languages and religions, most of them having enjoyed centuries of
> political autonomy, were able to create a modern territorial state as
> early as in 1848.
>
> *- Swiss Democracy by Wolf Linder*

I want to know what does the writer mean by "territorial state"? Does he mean a federal state?

Comment: Have you done [any research](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Territorial_state#:~:text=Rather%2C%20a%20territorial%20state%20reflects,typical%20of%20the%20modern%20era.)?

Comment: Yes I did - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Territorial_state
But I don't understand what this wikipedia page says and that's why I didn't mention it.

Comment: I do think the Wikipedia page is perhaps slightly confusing as it discusses the pre-modern era almost exclusively, whereas Wolf Linder is explicitly referring to a modern territorial state.  I understand the phrase compositionally as meaning a state that controls a particular territory and is modern.  It has nothing to do with federalism (I know Switzerland is federal, but that isn't being referenced here).

Comment: I think the modern equivalent is sovereign state.

Answer (score 1):

This is technical language. A territorial state is a state (a political object) that is tied to a particular territory (a country)

In the modern world all states are territorial states, but this hasn't always been the case throughout history. In particular some states in the past were personal states defined not by a country but by personal allegiance to a king or lord.

In this context "modern territorial state" means "state with a modern organisation based on an area of land with clearly defined borders."